# how to make an iconButton clickable in a stack which is in another stack

Tags: flutter, stack, flutter-onpressed, iconbutton

I'm new to flutter and I've this code which doesnt work because I get a red circle on my mouse when I try to click on one of my buttons, I've already been searching for days but I've n't found anything...
Hoewever I think the problem could be the stack into another one but anything is working even when I remove some widgets from my layout...

```
class EstablishmentCategoryProductsPricesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const EstablishmentCategoryProductsPricesList(
      {Key? key, required this.establishmentcategoryproductsprices})
      : super(key: key);

  final List<EstablishmentCategoryProductsPrices>
      establishmentcategoryproductsprices;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("--- BUILD EstablishmentCategoryProductPrice List ---");
    // final router = AutoRouter.of(context);
    return ResponsiveGridList(
      desiredItemWidth: ECPPVariables.bigboxwidth,
      minSpacing: ECPPVariables.space,
      children: List.generate(
        establishmentcategoryproductsprices.length,
        (index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: ECPPVariables.illustrationContainerColor,
              border:
                  Border.all(color: ECPPVariables.illustrationContainerColor),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: ECPPVariables.bigboxheight,
              width: ECPPVariables.bigboxwidth,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: ECPPVariables.illustrationContainerColor,
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: ECPPVariables.illustrationContainerColor),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(ECPPVariables.radiuscircular)),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                      ECPPFunctions.getImageSource(
                          establishmentcategoryproductsprices[index].image),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: ECPPVariables.illustrationContainerColor
                              .withOpacity(ECPPVariables.iContainerOpacity),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: ECPPVariables.illustrationContainerColor
                                  .withOpacity(
                                      ECPPVariables.iContainerOpacity)),
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                        ),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      establishmentcategoryproductsprices[
                                              index]
                                          .product,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: ECPPVariables.fontsize,
                                        color: ECPPVariables.fontcolor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      establishmentcategoryproductsprices[
                                                  index]
                                              .price
                                              .toString() +
                                          ' €',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: ECPPVariables.fontsize,
                                        color: ECPPVariables.fontcolor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        IconButton(
                                          onPressed:
                                              ECPPFunctions.deleteProduct(),
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            Icons.remove,
                                            size: ECPPVariables.iconsize,
                                            color: ECPPVariables.fontcolor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          ECPPFunctions.productCount()
                                              .toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: ECPPVariables.fontcolor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        IconButton(
                                          onPressed: ECPPFunctions.addProduct(),
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            Icons.add,
                                            size: ECPPVariables.iconsize,
                                            color: ECPPVariables.fontcolor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[the layout I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbMvt.png)

Comment: Why do you have so many `Columns`? They are kinda redundant

Comment: I use columns to dispoe the items on the layout

Comment: You can omit the most of your `Columns`. `Column` has a `children` property, which takes a `List` of `Widgets`.This means you can put more than 2 `Widgets`.

Comment: okay but what about my non clickable iconButton ? I 'd like them to be clickable